# Reindexing elasticsearch and delete old records

Tags: python, python-3.x, elasticsearch

I am trying to find a proper way how to reindex my elasticsearch index without downtime. I use [python library](https://elasticsearch-py.readthedocs.io/en/master/) for interacting with ES. The version of ES is [6.4](https://www.elastic.co/blog/elasticsearch-6-4-0-released).

Here is my workflow:

1. Create two aliases one for searching and one for indexing.
2. Point search alias to `old_index` and `new_index`
3. Point index alias to `new_index`
4. Call [reindex API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-reindex.html)
5. Wait for the reindexation process and remove search alias for `old_index`
6. Remove `old_index`

However this has one caveat in the form of duplicate records while I am reindexing. The record can be in both `old_index` and `new_index`.

Is there any way how to automatically delete records when they are moved `new_ index`?

I was trying something like this. Clearly this will delete all records in `new_index` instead of `old_index`

```
POST _reindex
{
  "source": {
    "index": "old_index"
  },
  "dest": {
    "index": "new_index",
  },
  "script": {
    "source": "ctx.op = 'delete'",
    "lang": "painless"
  }
}
```

Comment: Is your old_index static or will there be changes (inserts, updates, deletions) while reindexing?

Comment: Well, there can be some updates, deletions.

Comment: Then, keep in mind to use the search alias also for write operations as you need to publish the changes also to already reindexed documents in the new index.

Comment: Then you dont need to search in both indices while reindexing

Comment: I cannot set two aliases for writing operations. From doc: 'Only one index per alias can be assigned to be the write index '

Comment: Yes, you're right. Sorry for confusing.

Comment: Then you'll need to restart the reindex process with version_type:external after changing the update alias to the new index. Then all changes after _reindex start will be applied to the new index.

Comment: This won't solve duplicate results while reindexing, will it?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/182617/discussion-between-ibexit-and-joozty).